# "few but the most"

Tags: meaning

> *Sakharov devotes more than 1000 pages to constructing an argument that **few but the most** ardent Stalinists find compelling.*

I would like to ask what exactly the passage in bold means. I undrestood it that the argument is found compelling only by few people and these ones are just the ardent Stalinists. But my – may be wrong – understanding is based on the context of the sentence. From from the reading the very phrase I am not sure.

Comment: It means "few people other than the most ardent Stalinists"—in other words, those who were not the most ardent supporters of Stalin were extremely unlikely to be persuaded by the argument.

Comment: It means 'only the *most ardent* Stalinists find the argument  compelling, and they are few in number'.  Or, only a few ardent Stalinists find the argument compelling, and they can be characterized as the 'most ardent'.

Comment: *But* here has the sense *except*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...few people ***other than*** the most ardent Stalinists find the argument compelling.

So, those who would find the argument compelling are

- The most ardent Stalinists
- And few others